# how to find time complexity of a program?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I found this code to calculate cutting of String "Dynamic programming exercise for string cutting" 
this the code can anyone help me to find the  time complexity of it :

```
public static int findMinCutCost2(int[] m, int n) {
    if (m.length == 0)
        return 0;
    if (m.length == 1)
        return n;
    float half = n / 2f;
    int bestIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < m.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(half - m[bestIndex]) > Math.abs(half - m[i])) {
            bestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    int cl = 0, cr = 0;
    if (bestIndex > 0) {
        int[] ml = Arrays.copyOfRange(m, 0, bestIndex);
        int nl = m[bestIndex];
        cl = findMinCutCost2(ml, nl);
    }
    if (bestIndex < m.length - 1) {
        int[] mr = Arrays.copyOfRange(m, bestIndex + 1, m.length);
        int nr = n - m[bestIndex];
        for (int j = 0; j < mr.length; j++) {
            mr[j] = mr[j] - m[bestIndex];
        }
        cr = findMinCutCost2(mr, nr);
    }
    return n + cl + cr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total complexity is **`O(nlog(n))`**. Why: because for each array you are actually dividing it into two portion an each portion there are **n iteration**. 
There are atmost **log(n**) level and on each level there are **n loop**. so the total complexity is **O(nlog(n))**.

> For simplicity assume that array is always dividing into half. If not
>   even half, it will process first part (m.length-bestIndex) and second
>   part(bestIndex to length) which in total array size-> n.

```
          n              -> n loop
         / \
        /   \
       n/2   n/2         -->n/2 + n/2 loop
      / \    ...
     /   \
   n/4   n/4
```